# Building with unstable options results in a lot of errors

Tags: rust, operating-system

I'm following [this](https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/) blog, and am running into an issue when running `cargo bootimage` and `cargo run`. Here are a few of the errors (there are too many for me to post all of them):

```
error: requires `sized` lang_item
    --> /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde-1.0.197/src/de/value.rs:1710:25
     |
1710 |     impl<A, B> Pair for (A, B) {
     |                         ^^^^^^

error: requires `sized` lang_item
    --> /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde-1.0.197/src/de/impls.rs:1334:68
     |
1334 |                       struct TupleInPlaceVisitor<'a, $($name: 'a,)+>(&'a mut ($($name,)+));
     |                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
1366 | / tuple_impls! {
1367 | |     1  => (0 T0)
1368 | |     2  => (0 T0 1 T1)
1369 | |     3  => (0 T0 1 T1 2 T2)
...    |
1382 | |     16 => (0 T0 1 T1 2 T2 3 T3 4 T4 5 T5 6 T6 7 T7 8 T8 9 T9 10 T10 11 T11 12 T12 13 T13 14 T14 15 T15)
1383 | | }
     | |_- in this macro invocation
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `tuple_impls` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: requires `sized` lang_item
  --> /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde-1.0.197/src/de/size_hint.rs:24:19
   |
24 | fn helper(bounds: (usize, Option<usize>)) -> Option<usize> {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: requires `sized` lang_item
   --> /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde-1.0.197/src/ser/impls.rs:810:30
    |
810 | fn format_u8(mut n: u8, out: &mut [u8]) -> usize {
    |                              ^^^^^^^^^

error: requires `sized` lang_item
    --> /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde-1.0.197/src/private/de.rs:2825:17
     |
2825 |     recognized: &[&str],
     |                 ^^^^^^^

error: requires `sized` lang_item
  --> /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/serde-1.0.197/src/private/mod.rs:30:35
   |
30 |     pub fn from_utf8_lossy(bytes: &[u8]) -> Cow<str> {
   |                                   ^^^^^

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0405, E0412, E0425, E0432, E0433, E0463, E0531.
error: could not compile `serde` (lib) due to 6230 previous errors
```

Here is `main.rs`:

```rust
#![no_std] // don't link the Rust standard library
#![no_main] // disable all Rust-level entry points

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

static HELLO: &[u8] = b"Hello World!";

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    let vga_buffer = 0xb8000 as *mut u8;

    for (i, &byte) in HELLO.iter().enumerate() {
        unsafe {
            *vga_buffer.offset(i as isize * 2) = byte;
            *vga_buffer.offset(i as isize * 2 + 1) = 0xb;
        }
    }

    loop {}
}

/// This function is called on panic.
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

`.cargo/config.toml`:

```
[unstable]
unstable-options = true
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]

[build]
target = "aarch64-morb_os.json"
```

Config.toml:

```
[package]
name = "morb-os"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"

[dependencies]
bootloader = "0.11.7"
```

aarch64-morb_os.json:

```json
{
    "llvm-target": "aarch64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i8:8:32-i16:16:32-i64:64-i128:128-n32:64-S128",
    "arch": "aarch64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "+strict-align,+neon,+fp-armv8"
}
```

I tried executing everything manually, but that resulted in the same errors. I think the problem might have to do with my current rust install?

Comment: Why do you need to use "unstable"?

Comment: I need to use "unstable" to recompile the standard library on demand so that I can support custom targets (at least, according to the blog I am following).

Comment: The error suggests missing `core` install. But this is strange, since you have `build-std = ["core"]`.